# jquery template value is array or string - how to handle

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

So I want to <br/> if value is array otherwise just display the value.
I guess I can write a function to do this but wondering if there's a better way to do this with jquery template?

```
<script id="template" type="x-jquery-tmpl"> <table>
  <tr>
    <td>${name}</td>
    <td>{{each value}}${$value}<br/>{{/each}}</td>
  </tr> </table>
</script>

<script>
      var data = [
                    {
                        name: "blah",
                        value: ["1", "2", "3"]
                    },
                    {
                        name: "blah blah",
                        value : "abc"
                    }
                ];

$('#template').tmpl(data).appendTo('#target);
    </script>

<div id="target">

</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<script id="template" type="x-jquery-tmpl"> <table>
  <tr>
    <td>${name}</td>
    {{if typeof value == 'array'}}
        <td>{{each value}}${$value}<br/>{{/each}}</td>
    {{/if}}
    {{else}}
        <td>${value}<br/></td>
    {{/else}}
  </tr> </table>
</script>
```